# How to get the value of a single element from a SOAP response? (Java)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, dom

I want to get the "SearchResult" value from the following InputStream:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
        <SearchResponse xmlns="[url here]">
            <SearchResult>[THIS VALUE HERE]</SearchResult>
        </SearchResponse>
      </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I've been trying to use a DOM parser but am having trouble, and am not sure if it is the right approach anyway:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db;
Document doc = null;

db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(soapResponse));
doc = db.parse(inStream);  

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("SearchResult");
//Not sure how to get the value... Everything I've tried returned "null". Help?
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java and Android level 8 or newer:
`nodeList.item(0).getTextContent()`

For android level 1 and newer:
`nodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()`

Comment: I haven't, because that gives me the error "Call requires API level 8 (current min is 7)..."

Comment: Hmm... works for me, with Java 6. But I see that you've added the Android tag.... so now you learn a hard lesson: Android IS NOT Java. (Android != Java). This is a problem with your target android version ... do you need to be android 2.1.x compatible?

Comment: Updated with an answer that will work for api level 1 android

Comment: I knew that Java and Android had their differences, but I thought they wouldn't matter in this case -- lesson learned! Thanks a bunch, that did it!